# C embedded error: ‘XXXX’ declared as function returning a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fortran, c-preprocessor, lapacke

I'm attempting to cross-compile the LAPACK library (fortran) and the C API, LAPACKE for bare-metal embedded targets powerpc-eabi target, using the gcc cross compilers for this target. Compiling proceeds but eventually hits this error:

```
[ 44%] Building C object LAPACKE/CMakeFiles/lapacke.dir/src/lapacke_cbbcsd.c.obj
cd /home/rcrozier/build/powerpc-eabi/lapack/LAPACKE && /usr/local/powerpc-eabi/bin/powerpc-eabi-gcc  -DADD_ -mcpu=750 -I/home/rcrozier/src/fast-v8-hg/cross-dependancies/lapack-3.6.0/LAPACKE/include    -o CMakeFiles/lapacke.dir/src/lapacke_cbbcsd.c.obj   -c /home/rcrozier/src/fast-v8-hg/cross-dependancies/lapack-3.6.0/LAPACKE/src/lapacke_cbbcsd.c
In file included from /home/rcrozier/src/fast-v8-hg/cross-dependancies/lapack-3.6.0/LAPACKE/include/lapacke_utils.h:37:0,
                 from /home/rcrozier/src/fast-v8-hg/cross-dependancies/lapack-3.6.0/LAPACKE/src/lapacke_cbbcsd.c:34:
/home/rcrozier/src/fast-v8-hg/cross-dependancies/lapack-3.6.0/LAPACKE/include/lapacke.h:145:22: error: ‘LAPACK_GLOBAL’ declared as function returning a function
 #define LAPACK_lsame LAPACK_GLOBAL(lsame,LSAME)
                      ^
```

This error occurs when building the C interface to LAPACK, LAPACKE.

A [post on the LAPACK forums](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4564) suggests this is a problem with Fortran name mangling, and to add the `-DADD_` processor flag. Above I have attempted this, but it makes no difference.

The preprocessor define is used in a header file, copied below:

```
#ifndef LAPACK_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define LAPACK_HEADER_INCLUDED

#ifndef LAPACK_GLOBAL
#if defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_LC) || defined(ADD_)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname##_
#elif defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_UC) || defined(UPPER)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  UCNAME
#elif defined(LAPACK_GLOBAL_PATTERN_MC) || defined(NOCHANGE)
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname
#else
#define LAPACK_GLOBAL(lcname,UCNAME)  lcname##_
#endif
#endif

#endif
```

The error occurs in another header file which uses `LAPACK_GLOBAL` like so:

```
#include "lapacke_mangling.h"

#define LAPACK_lsame LAPACK_GLOBAL(lsame,LSAME)
lapack_logical LAPACK_lsame( char* ca,  char* cb,
                              lapack_int lca, lapack_int lcb );
```

The `lapacke_mangling.h` file contents is shown below:

```
#ifndef LAPACK_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define LAPACK_HEADER_INCLUDED

#endif
```

The error does not occur when building natively, or when building for another linux target, `powerpc-linux-gnu`.

Can anyone explain the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest a [tag:c-preprocessor] tag instead one of the less relevant tags ([tag:compiler-errors] or [tag:bare-metal]). Do you know which if branch is taken by the pre-processor in your case? Which of the tested macros branches is or is not defined?

Comment: I added the suggested tag, and to answer, no, I don't know for sure, I will see if I can figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was that the preprocessor header file was not actually used with the cmake build system, instead a different header was supposed to be generated by cmake. Cmake did not generate the file corectly (probably because of cross-compilation). The patch below modifies the lapacke CMakeLists to add an option to force the use of this header file.

```
--- CMakeLists.txt  2017-11-30 12:07:46.007080017 +0000
+++ newCMakeLists.txt   2017-11-30 12:06:54.491078643 +0000
@@ -3,11 +3,18 @@

 set(LAPACK_INSTALL_EXPORT_NAME lapacke-targets)

+option(FORCE_LAPACKE_MANGLING_WITH_FLAGS "Force the use of the lapack_mangling_with_flags.h header rather than automatic detection" OFF)
+
 # Create a header file netlib.h for the routines called in my C programs
-include(FortranCInterface)
-FortranCInterface_HEADER( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lapacke_mangling.h
-                          MACRO_NAMESPACE "LAPACK_"
-                          SYMBOL_NAMESPACE "LAPACK_" )
+if (FORCE_LAPACKE_MANGLING_WITH_FLAGS)
+    # copy the lapacke_mangling_with_flags.h to lapacke_mangling.h
+    configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lapacke_mangling_with_flags.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lapacke_mangling.h)
+else (FORCE_LAPACKE_MANGLING_WITH_FLAGS)
+    include(FortranCInterface)
+    FortranCInterface_HEADER( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lapacke_mangling.h
+                              MACRO_NAMESPACE "LAPACK_"
+                              SYMBOL_NAMESPACE "LAPACK_" )
+endif (FORCE_LAPACKE_MANGLING_WITH_FLAGS)

 # Old way to detect mangling
 #include(FortranMangling)
```

With this, my definitions were picked up and the appropriate mangling applied.